# How to get a specific value out an an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

I have the follow array and and am trying to get the meta_value for the the object that has the meta_key of license_number.  How can I return that value?

```
items: [
{
    account_id: "7890",
    t: 1990007,
    meta_value: "27",
    id: "123",
    create_date: 1507174015113,
    update_date: 1512628710384,
    meta_key: "content_items",
},
{
    account_id: "7890",
    t: 1990007,
    meta_value: "123456",
    id: "123",
    create_date: 1498492590855,
    update_date: 1498492590855,
    meta_key: "location_id",
},
{
    account_id: "7890",
    t: 1990007,
    meta_value: "123456789",
    id: "123",
    create_date: 1498492590855,
    update_date: 1498492590855,
    meta_key: "license_number",
}
]
```

Comment: Loop it, use an if statement.. basic things. Have you took the steps to try to find out? Where is your attempt? Have you googled 'how to access an object' ? Sigh

Comment: Please check this https://3v4l.org/sMlho

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php)() and a callable to fit your needs (here an anonymous fonction) :

```
$searchedValue = 'license_number';
$o = array_filter( $items,
    function ($e) use (&$searchedValue) {
        return $e->meta_key == $searchedValue;
    }
);
```

Note the return is an array of objects containing all values that fit the condition. This will give you the first result.

```
reset($o);
```